# XSS PHP Input/Output

Tags: php, xss

Hi Question about XSS and PHP......

I am building a PHP Application all input is going to the database via client then server side validation, sanitization using filtervar.....encrypted passwords stored in the database, if I a type in scripttag -- whatever -- script tag it gets stored in the database as just that, and it can't do any harm there.

Is XSS only a threat when input is being directly outputted and and the only time to use htmlentities is at the point of outputting inputted data from the user.

My App doesn't do this, but is there a way for a would be attacker to inject some malicious code and cause it to be outputted, even though my programming logic doesn't allow for this.

I want to have all bases covered.........

Look forward to your answers.........
Yes I'm using PDO prepared statements, bindParam, execute to prevent SQL Injection, and to store the data safely in the database, I'm also using :

```
 if(filter_var($_POST['firstname'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)){
            $clean['firstname'] = $_POST['firstname'];
            };
```

For the Sanitization could that be improved on...........

I just fixed the code, the if statement was preventing the filter var from sanitizing the script tags see below :

```
$clean =  array();
        $clean['firstname'] = (filter_var($_POST['firstname'],     FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));


            $clean['lastname'] = (filter_var($_POST['lastname'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));


            $clean['username'] = (filter_var($_POST['username'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
```

Now the script tags are no longer in the database.........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Input

If you have properly sanitized or validated things using filtervar then you probably do not have any problems on the database end.  Sometimes it's hard to know if you have covered all your bases.  Your database queries should still probably use parameterized queries to protect you.

### Output

You should properly escape data for the target content type if any user input can be seen by other users; even things like a username can be malicious.

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you showed a few code examples of how you're using filter_var().  However, in general, here are some things to consider:

- filter_var() can be a great tool.  Also, you might look into the library HTMLPurifier.  I've had a lot of success with that.  The goal is to remove bad content before it even gets to the database.
- use prepared statements to insert your data into the database.  While this has a tad bit of extra weight when used for only a single query, it is the best way to insert data directly to the database with the least risk of sql injection.
- Use htmlentities() *AND* the proper encoding when you output your data.  For example, do not allow UTF-8 data in your database but output ISO 8859-1 output.  I always suggest making sure your document encoding, database, and all filtering methods all work with the same encoding, preferably UTF-8
- Don't forget that $_SERVER is not clean in PHP.  Many people do tons of filtering and HTML entities, but use the unsanitized version of $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] in forms

If you'd like specific help, please post code samples.

Comment: What do you think of how I've used filtervar? I was using ctype_alnum, but when I typed in say o'reilly as the lastname it came up as null in the database............Are there better forms of sanitization in php, but also I guess it depends on the type of input as to what you would use.....I'll take a look at html purifier.....thanks

Comment: Generally, like I said, I use HTMLPurifier.  I tend not to use the built in SANITIZE constants for filter_var().  Instead, I've used the callback version - and passed it to my own method.  There, I've created regular expressions to remove 'bad' stuff.  But, I found I still missed a lot.  That's why its best to sanitize before the DB and filter after. :)  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I will use HTML Purifier......but right now prefer to implement myself as I'm still learning the principles. Just checked out the Filter Callback looks like a good way to give you the specific control of the data you need. Thanks.....